# How to get all model objects from a Wicket datatable

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using a Wicket `DefaultDataTable`. It contains some text fields that the user is supposed to put values in. The table is in a form. When I submit the form, I want to get hold of all the "rows" so that I can iterate through them. I don't want to use AJAX.

I've managed to bind the table to a "Contact" object, with an `EditablePropertyColumn` that shows the right fields and input boxes in the columns I want.

How can I get hold of the row items? `dataTable.getDefaultModelObject()` returns `null` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can you show us the form code?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, it sounds like you have some other (more fundamental) thing wrong.  As martin-g mentions, the editable property column uses a property model, which means that when the form is submitted (if all validation, etc, passes), it will call setObject on that model, which in turn will call setFoo (where "foo" is the property for that column) on the POJO that backs that row of data in your table.

You could (as Don mentions) use a visitor to iterate through the children of your table.  However, in general, this means that you're doing something else wrong.  Wicket is written so that you do not have to go pull data from a form submission and push it yourself onto your POJOs.  The model should do that for you.  You should not be "pushing" data around yourself.

Showing some code would help, but short of that: wherever your table gets its data from (some list of Contacts, etc) - try to just pull the data from those same objects.  It should already be populated for you.  If it's not, post some code - especially where you're initializing the table and its data provider.

Answer (score 2):

The submitted data is populated in the Contact object. This is how PropertyColumn works.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question: In a datatable thats added to a form, (ie the datatable listing a bunch of contactobject) how can in get the datatable rows and iterate through them in the onsubmit button?

Comment: should be "how can i get the datatable rows and iterate through them in the onsubmit override when pressing the form submitbutton"

Comment: But yes it does... The data is put into the Contact object, which is available from your DataProvider. So there is no need to access the rows, just grab the list from the provider and iterate on this one.

Answer (score 1):

the DefaultDataTable have a method newRowItem in thath method you can catch the models that are displayed of the table:

```
  private List<IModel<T>> models= new LinkedList<IModel<T>>();
    @Override
    protected Item<T> newRowItem(final String id, int index,
            final IModel<T> model) {
              models.add(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to be specific if you showed the code you've got, but I can think of two general approaches to this.

One way is to just maintain a list of references to the models somewhere outside the `DefaultDataTable` as you're constructing it.

If it's difficult to find a way to do that, another possible approach is to use an implementation of Wicket's `IVisitor` to search the components inside your datatable for components containing the models.

The `WebMarkupContainer` class has a method

```
public final <S extends Component> Object visitChildren(final Class<?> clazz,
    final IVisitor<S> visitor)
```

which can be used to traverse all contained components of a specific class, and a method

```
public final Object visitChildren(final IVisitor<Component> visitor)
```

which does the same but without restricting to a specific class.

The `IVisitor<T extends Component>` interface requires you to define a method

```
public Object component(T component)
```

which is called by these "visit" methods with each component found as argument.  The return value is a signal to continue or exit the traversal, and the method you define can collect things it finds in the component into a list.